# Checking for null - what order?

Tags: java

When checking for nulls I use this:

```
String str;

if(str == null){
    //...
}
```

but I've seen this as well:

```
if(null == str){
    //...
}
```

Is there any advantage of using one over the other? Or is it just to improve readability?

Comment: If you use this to guard against null parameters, [`T Objects.requireNonNull(T[, String])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) might be of your interest.

Comment: it does make a diff (in Java) if checking for boolean conditions to protect against human error of typing something like if(value = true) when you meant if(value == true). Easily done and hard to track down bugs can result from this kind of stuff!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The second version ( `null == str` ) is called a **yoda condition**.

They both result in the same behavior, but the second one has one advantage: It prevents you from accidentally changing a variable, when you forget one `=`. In that case the compiler returns an error at that row and you're not left with some weird behavior of your code and the resulting debugging.

Comment: It depends. As user thkala points out correctly, in Java it doesn't matter. In C it does, however, modern compilers such as LLVM's Clang warn you about this with a "Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses".

Comment: Thanks Sirko, it makes sense to me :)

Answer (score 38):

The `null == x` convention is usually found in code written by people familiar with C, where an assignment can also be an expression. Some C programmers write code like this so that if they miss an `=` in

```
if (NULL == ptr)...
```

the code will not compile, since `NULL = ptr` is not a valid assignment. This prevents a rather sneaky error from being introduced in the code-base, although modern C compilers make make such conventions obsolete, as long as one takes care to enable and *read* the generated warnings...

This coding style has never had any usefulness in Java, where reference assignments cannot be used as boolean expressions. It could even be considered counter-intuitive; in their natural language most people will say *"if X is null..."*, or *"if X is equal to 17..."*,  rather than *"if null is equal to X..."*.

Comment: *This coding style has never had any usefulness in Java*  imagine that `boolean b=... if (b=isXXX()){...}` and compare to `boolean b=... if (isXXX()==b){}`

Comment: @bestsss: I edited my answer to clarify this point. That said, your second snippet could very well be more intuitive than the first in some contexts, depending on whether `b` can be deemed a local constant. `if (false == myFlag)...` is not quite the same though...

Comment: point is that in the 1st snippet if equivalent of `boolean b;... b=isXXX(); if (b){...}` which is valid, but it can be a mistake as well. For example `boolean b=isYYY(); if (b=isXXX()){}` which doesn't compare `isYYY() to isXXX()` - indeed java it's less prone to the same mistake in C but still possible.

Comment: @bestsss: agreed, `if (b == false)...` is valid code and a Yoda-style condition could indeed prevent an error here. That does not make it any more clear or maintainable, though...

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference between the two other than readability. Use whichever makes more sense to you.

Comment: Indeed. Although I can add that I've never seen anyone use the 'null == str' variety, so I'd recommend using the first version because it's simply more conventional.

Comment: The latter sounds like a Yoda condition.

Comment: Wasn't this also used back in the day to mitigate issues with using a single `=` instead of `==`? `if (str=null)` is valid, but `if (null =str)` isn't.

Comment: @climbage Yes, but in Java only boolean expressions can be used in if statements, so there's really no difference here.

Comment: @Jeffrey Right, I just figured it might help explain why you would every see the expression in that order in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated readability is the most important reason.  Reading it out loud, the (null == str) does not read well.  It's almost like reading right to left.  (str == null) reads much better.

In addition, I think the following needs to be taken into consideration:

```
if (str != null)  
if (str == null)
```

vs.

```
if (null != str)
if (null == str)
```

I would expect the positive (str == null) and the negative to be written in the same manner, which is another reason I would favor the top set.

Answer (score 2):

`if(a==b) {}` is the same as `if(b==a) {}` , and the same is true if b was null. It's just a style/order difference as far as functionality, at least in java.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (null == str) {
}
```

is a programming idiom from c/c++, where the assignment operator `=` can be used to resolve to a true/false statement. For example in c if you want to check if I can open a stream in c/c++, you can

```
if (myStream = openStream())
```

which sets opens and assigns in one line. However, this means that people often type `=` when they mean `==`, and it would be valid syntax in c: for example `if (x = 5)` will always resolve to true, when they really mean `if (x ==5)`. So people write `if (5 == x)` so if you leave out a `=` your code won't compile.

This doesn't apply to java.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference. However the second is considered less error prone. In the first case you would not get an error if you tried to do

```
String str;

if(str = null){
}
```

which is something you usually don't do in conditionals.

Also, you get to think about the actual condition first, which is a good practice.

Comment: You do in fact get an error in Java: Error, incompatible types. Found java.lang.String Required boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Some developers argue that `var == null` is more error-prone than `null == var`. Their argument is that you might accidentally assign the variable instead of doing a null-check.

But only when the variable you test against `null` is a `Boolean` you can accidentally use the `=` instead of `==` and it will compile.

```
Boolean checked = Boolean.TRUE;
if(checked = null){ // accidentally assigned null and compiles
}
```

Only in this case the assignment compiles, because the conditional expression must evaluate to a boolean value. See [JLS-14.9.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) Since the assignment expression itself evaluates to a boolean type, it compiles. But you will get a `NullPointerException` at runtume, because java will try to unbox the `checked` variable which is `null`.

If you use any other type then `Boolean` you will get a compiler error. E.g.

```
String str = "hello";
if(str = null){ // compiler error, because str = null doesn't evaluate to a boolean
}
```

My conclusion is that error situations are extremly rare and you can easily write unit tests that detect such errors.

So write the if-statement it in the way it is more readable.

I think "*if name is null*" makes more sense then "*if null is name*".