# Validating string in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking for null - what order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983573/checking-for-null-what-order)

Can anyone please tell me what is the better approach in validating a string value for 'null' and why?

```
String user = userService.getUserName(accID);

1) if(user != null) {
    ..
   }

2) if(null != user) {
    ..
   }
```

Comment: If I correctly understood you problem please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null

Answer (score 2):

There is no differnece. The first version is more commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

For this case it doesn't matter, alltough the first aproach is more common.

However but when feeding it directly into an equals method, the so-called yoda-condition is prefered.

eg:

```
if("".equals(string)){
}
```

is prefered over

```
if(string.equals("")){
}
```

because it avoids nullpointer exceptions

Comment: Yoda condition with == also avoids *something*---accidental assignment instead of comparison. Since this is a compiler warning by default, though, there's not much sense in guarding against it with unnatural syntax.

Comment: agreed, however within an if statement it only realy can happen with Boolean classes anyway. All other classes will result in a "this will not result in a boolean" kind of error.

Comment: True... most often this will occur not when comparing against a literal (which wouldn't make sense for a boolean anyway), but when comparing two boolean values. In that particular case, however, code could really get obfuscated if it weren't for the compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

First approach is mostly used by developers. I don't think it makes difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen both approaches. Some people believe it is better to give the value you are comparing to first. This is maybe better if you have many alternatives to see the value you are comparing to first.

I personally use the first option because this is my habit.

I doubt there is any performance difference if that is your question. All the difference is in the code style and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no functional difference to it and the first is more readable, you should choose the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of taste in this case.

In other cases, e.g. if you would compare against a string literal/constant, I would prefer this:

```
if ("yourStringConstant".equals(yourVariable))
```

as this would also handle the case when yourVariable would be null. If you would do it the other way, you would get a NullPointerException:

```
if (yourVariable.equals("yourStringConstant"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The second approach comes from C/C++. When you write `if (user = null)` instead of `if (user == null)` in C you'll get a logical error, but not a compilation one, and such an error may be really difficult to detect.

But in case you write `if(null = user)` instead of `if(null == user)` you'll get a compilation error as you cannot assign a variable to `null`. That's why reversed order of arguments is often used there.

However in Java this doesn't make much sense as Java compiler won't take a `if(user = null)` expression, so you can use any approach. The first one is more widespread though

Comment: If `user` happens to be a `Boolean`, there will be no compiler error.

Comment: Didn't know that. Why does this happen?

Comment: Due to autoboxing -- the type of the entire expression `boolVar = null` is `Boolean`, boxed to `boolean` inside `if`. At runtime it always throws an NPE, of course.