# Inverse comparison/equals arguments

Tags: javascript, optimization, coding-style

I saw many times in open source projects that folks write something like that:

```js
if("" !== foo) {
    // ...
}
```

Why on earth do they do that? I mean you are checking if *foo's* value is empty string or not. I understand that `"" !== foo` and `foo !== ""` means exactly the same. But what's the reason to write tricky and less obvious code?

Comment: similar explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10983573/1169798

Comment: Yoda conditions, use them you will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm personally not a fan of this style, either; however, the style stems from this:

```
 if (x = "") { // **oops**, meant to do "==" but ended up assigning to "x"
    // ...
 }
```

The "if" statement here will cause an unintended side-effect. There are a number of languages in which side effects and implicit conversions to boolean make it easy to shoot oneself in the foot this way (JavaScript and C++ come to mind). To avoid this, some have the convention of inverting the ordering, since assigning to a constant will produce a more immediate and obvious error. I'm personally not a fan of this, because it makes the code read less like English ("if x equals the empty string" reads more naturally than "if empty string equals x"), and better tooling (linters, source code analyzers, etc.) can catch these just as effectively.