# Best way to check null?

Tags: java

Some people recommend ***method 2*** for `null`-check, but I am not sure what's the reason behind it and why it should be preferred?

```
Date test1 = null; // test1 can be any object like String instead of Date
if (test1 != null) {
  System.out.println("Test");
}
```

**Method 2:-**

```
Date test1 = null;
if (null != test1) {
  System.out.println("Test");
}
```

Comment: See in the description of the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983573/checking-for-null-what-order The reason for method 2 to be better is that you get a compiler error when you are missing one "=".

Comment: @ReneM. But we're talking about java here. Even `if(test=null)` would give a compiler error since this is not a boolean ...

Comment: @ReneM. It is an unequals check if you Forget an equals sign you get `test1 ! null`

Comment: Or since java 1.7: `if (Objects.isNull(whatever))`  ... prefer the oneliner!

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? The title suggest it but the question is about unequals not about equals

Comment: @Jens What difference would it make (except reversed results)?

Comment: @Pshemo in `==` you can forget one equals sign and oversee it in the review. But in case of  `!=`?Also as ReneM mentioned you get an error if you forget it.

Comment: @GhostCat it is Java8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object- There is also a nonNull function

Comment: I recommend the first because of the readability - one would speak like "if the variable is null, then...", not yoda-style "if null the variable is...". There is the risk of assignment instead of comparison, but there are more risks like that, and even if you do it, that is an easy bug to find. Readability is more important. (Of course, this is nothing but an opinion - you might opt to try both styles and see what you prefer for yourself.)

Comment: @Jens I know, but he ask for the reason why alot of people say solution 2 is best. It's the only reason. The result is after compiler optimization the same.

Comment: Probably you are aware of that, but just for the record: although the question got closed, you are still free to accept one of the answers ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Java 7 introduced [java.lang.Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) with nice little helper methods such as `requireNonNull()`. Java 8 added a few more, especially `isNull()` and `nonNull()`. They were meant to be used for stream() operations; but of course, they are not restricted to that scenario.

So, one alternative option would to simply rely on those new methods to make such decisions. Concise, readable, "standard; and preventing you from repeating your own check all over the place. And zero chance to introduce and kind of typos. Of course, minimal overhead from having another method call. On the hand: if your method is called millions of times - it will be JIT'ed anyway; and then such small methods might be inlined easily.

Comment: Sure, I had no beef with the answer per se.

Comment: Still: thanks for your valuable feedback. After 3 days with 250 rep each; I can't get down any significant answers lately. So I strive at least for perfection with those that I get half-right initially ... hoping that some "better" questions show up again at some point ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference here. Both conditions will work same way. Discussion most likely came from [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) where we write:

```
 null          ==         temp1
literal    comparison    variable
```

which prevents us from making mistake of writing `=` (assignment operator) instead of `==` (comparison) when we could end up with code like `if (foo = 42)` which in some languages compiles fine causing logical errors possibly hard to find (especially by novice programmer).

But in your case you don't need to use that construct. There are at lest two reasons for that:

1. You are using `!=` not `==`, so there is very low chance that you would write only `=` instead of `!=`
2. In Java `if (expression)` expect `expression` to return `boolean` value, so even if by mistake you write `= null` such code will **not compile** since expression will return `null`. That prevents us from running code with such typo.

   Yoda condition in Java only makes sense for `boolean` expressions like `if (stop == true)`, but even then instead of writing `if (true == stop)` we should simply skip `== true` (or `==false`) part since we already have boolean value. So we should write `if (stop)` or `if (!stop)` instead.

Using such style makes sense when you are programming in different languages and you want to simplify your life by using one style which helps in one language and at the same time doesn't cause problems in other languages (even if it is not really necessary there).

Still it is worth knowing where construct/style is helpful or necessary and where it is not since each language may have better way of handling that matter like already mentioned in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43657628/1393766) `Objects.nonNull`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of plausible reasons for this. The first is a hold-over from C. In C:

```
if(x = NULL) { ... }
```

... (note single `=`) is a mistake some developers might accidentally make.

```
if(NULL = x) { ... }
```

... causes a compiler error. So if you're in the habit of putting the `null` first, it's harder to make this mistake.

*However* this logic doesn't apply to `!=`, so the only reason to continue putting the `null` first is for consistency.

... and in Java `if(x = null)` is also a compiler error because Java does not evaluate an assignment into a value.

There is another situation in which putting the "expected" before the "actual" is common, and that is:

```
if("expected string".equals(string)) { ... }
```

Because `"expected string"` definitely isn't `null`, this can't `NullPointerException` when `string == null`, whereas `string.equals("expected string")` would.

So, some programmers get in the habit of putting the expected value first.

My own preference is for something that reads similar to an English sentence, and to me: `if(x == null)` is better in that respect.

Some of the tricks we used to do to catch little bugs and typos, are made less necessary by unit-testing habits, by avoiding nulls in the first place, and by judicious use of `final` variables.

Comment: 1. `if(x=null)` get also an error in Java. 2. OP's variable is a date not a string

Comment: @Jens 1. Already edited to point out it's a C habit that's carried forward. 2. The point is that the String idiom leads to habits in programmers - and the technique applies to any object type anyway.

Comment: And how 2. works for OP's question: `if (null != test1) {`